# Atmega328 xbee and softaware serial libraries

Tags: atmega328, xbee

I use an atmega328 with fdti cable wired at rx/tx and i want to connect a zigbee s2 at diferrent pins. I have tried to use  SoftwareSerial library but i would like to use the xbee library too. Is there a way to use both libraries? If there is no way doing this, is it a problem to connect both fdti cable and zigbee at the same rx/tx? In the future, in opposition to fdti cable i will use a micro usb avr.